# Logstash/JDBC config in ELK Docker setup

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I'm using https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk (version 7.5.2)and I can't configure Logstash pipeline to work. My .conf file is:

```
input {
  jdbc {
      jdbc_driver_library => "/home/administrator/elk/extensions/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar"
      jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
      jdbc_user => "root"
      jdbc_password => ""
      schedule => "* * * * *"
      statement => "SELECT * FROM test.users where regdate >:sql_last_value;"
      use_column_value => true
      tracking_column => "regdate"
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        user => "elastic"
        password => "somepassword"
    index => "test"
    }
  stdout { 
    codec => json_lines 
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably the path to the driver is wrong, as long you dont changed the logstash service - verify the running logstash container if the driver is present at that location. Do you have any error messages?

Comment: What is not working? What is your error message?

Comment: LogStash::PluginLoadingError
 unable to load /home/administrator/elk/logstash/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar from :jdbc_driver_library, no such file to load -- /home/administrator/elk/logstash/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19

Comment: I did place the file in the correct folder and permissions are good.

Comment: The jdbc_driver_library repository is to locate in the docker container, not on your server. Did you check in the container ? Otherwise you may have to add some command in your Dockerfile as : "RUN mkdir -p /home/administrator/elk/extensions/" & "RUN curl -o /home/administrator/elk/extensions/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar https://downloads..."